# NetworkExtension iOS 11

Tags: ios11, networkextension

I'm using the NEHotspotHelper API. In iOS 11 beta 8 is happening a strange behavior in the command filterScanList.
The networks that I delivered they aren't displaying with the message of key kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName.
I need to turn off/turn on the Wi-Fi for displaying them. It's a bug?

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get filterScanList, I am not able to get this SSID list.

Comment: You need enter in wifi screen, the system will call filterScanList in your helper.